# How to read data with fixed rows (multiples spaces) without removing charcters using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to read a fixed width **file.txt** using pandas like this :

```
option19971675181       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134                            111155.555   669   166   666
option19971675182       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134                           111115.555  6660 66515  4660
option19971675182       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA                              111155.555    66   662   160
option19971675182       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 Noe                       111155.555    62    68    62
option19971675189       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 NoeQWED                   111115.555     0     0     0
option19971675189       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 eQWED                    111115.555     0    55     0
option19971675189       ACHILLE 7gt BLA BLA 13                            111155.555   662    96   164
option19971675189       ACHILLE 879 BLA BLA                               111155.555   663    69    60
option19971675189       ACHILLE 897 BLA BLA 134                           11115.555  5555  5555  5555
```

I tried to read the file into pandas.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delimiter ="\s\s+", header = None)
```

The problem that in columns 2 i have more than one space so it still show error :
`Skipping line 16: Expected 5 fields in line 136, saw 6. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.`

Also `pd.read_fwf` is not a good solution in this case: I already tried :

```
 df= pd.read_fwf("test.txt", colspecs="infer", header=None)
```

And if use this line of code

> df

```
                   0        1    2    3    4      5        6                             7
0  option19971675181  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0      NaN  111155.555   669   166   666
1  option19971675182  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0      NaN  111115.555  6660 66515  4660
2  option19971675182  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA    NaN      NaN  111155.555    66   662   160
3  option19971675182  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0      Noe  111155.555    62    68    62
4  option19971675189  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0  NoeQWED  111115.555     0     0     0
5  option19971675189  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0    eQWED  111115.555     0    55     0
6  option19971675189  ACHILLE  7gt  BLA  BLA   13.0      NaN  111155.555   662    96   164
7  option19971675189  ACHILLE  879  BLA  BLA    NaN      NaN  111155.555   663    69    60
8  option19971675189  ACHILLE  897  BLA  BLA  134.0      NaN   11115.555  5555  5555  5555
```

The df that i want :

```
                   0        1                                       2        3     4      5
0  option19971675181  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0             111155.555   669   166   666
1  option19971675182  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0             111115.555  6660 66515  4660
2  option19971675182  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA                    111155.555    66   662   160
3  option19971675182  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0  Noe        111155.555    62    68    62
4  option19971675189  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0  NoeQWED    111115.555     0     0     0
5  option19971675189  ACHILLE  BLA  BLA  BLA  134.0    eQWED    111115.555     0    55     0
6  option19971675189  ACHILLE  7gt  BLA  BLA   13.0             111155.555   662    96   164
7  option19971675189  ACHILLE  879  BLA  BLA                    111155.555   663    69    60
8  option19971675189  ACHILLE  897  BLA  BLA  134.0             11115.555    5555  5555  5555
```

Please note that **col 3 & 4 & 5** are sometimes separated only by one space or 2 maximum

Can someone help please to get all my data without losing value.

Comment: `read_fwf` seems to work well for me when I copy paste your sample data in a text file and run the last line you mentioned in your question. If you copy paste your sample in a txt file and you use `read_fwf` is data still lost? If it works on that data can you update the sample data in your question for which the code does fail so the problem is reproducible? Also it might not matter, but what version of `pandas` are you using? I'm using `1.3.1`.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden please check the update

Comment: Good update. Do you have max widths for these columns in mind or do you only have the spaces to go on? Like let's say the first column is max 20 characters the next 40, etc...? Because if you do you can define where which columns starts and ends.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Actually i dont have specific widths for these columns

Comment: What is your cut-off point for these columns? `3` or more spaces between values means a new column or tabs maybe? I would try `read_csv` and try a delimiter based on this cut-off point.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Yes exactly, I think the problem is that all rows in col 3, 4 and 5 are separated with 3 spaces expect one row that is seperated with one space